# Accessing parsed JSON objects

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, parsing

```
data = '{"abc":null, "data":[{"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":{"id":76, "type":"guest"}}, {"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":{"id":73, "type":"member"}}]}'

a = json.loads(data)
print(a["data"]["info"]["type"])

Output: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I need to know how to solve this, to the output be: `["guest", "member"]`.

**Edit:** : Thank you for the answers, I solved the problem, but I am trying to learn, so can I ask what to do if the data contains a null value?

Example:

```
import json

data = '{"abc":null, "data":[{"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":{"id":76, "type":"guest"}}, {"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":{"id":73, "type":"member"}}, {"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":null}]}'

a = json.loads(data)
print([t["info"]["type"] for t in json.loads(data)["data"]])

Output: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's what then? and how I fix that?

Comment: You forgot to mention `a` in the expression. `a["data"][0]["info"]["type"]`.

Comment: The `data` string in your question is invalid JSON format and `json.loads()` produces the following error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 93 (char 92)`. Please [edit] your question and fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, there was mistake in JSON text syntax I have corrected it.

```
import json
data = '{"abc":null, "data":[{"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":{"id":76, "type":"guest"}}, {"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":{"id":73, "type":"member"}}, {"admin":0, "customer":"no", "info":null}]}'
print([(t["info"]["type"] if t["info"] else None) for t in json.loads(data)["data"]])
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you check the edit and help me solve this new problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is piece by piece:

```
>>> a
{'abc': None, 'data': [{'admin': 0, 'customer': 'no', 'info': {'id': 76, 'type': 'guest'}}, {'admin': 0, 'customer': 'no', 'info': {'id': 73, 'type': 'member'}}]}
>>> a['data']
[{'admin': 0, 'customer': 'no', 'info': {'id': 76, 'type': 'guest'}}, {'admin': 0, 'customer': 'no', 'info': {'id': 73, 'type': 'member'}}]
>>> [d['info'] for d in a['data']]
[{'id': 76, 'type': 'guest'}, {'id': 73, 'type': 'member'}]
>>> [d['info']['type'] for d in a['data']]
['guest', 'member']
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you check the edit and help me solve this new problem? Thank you.

Comment: Please post a new question if you have a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that should give you the desired result. Since you changed your code along the way, I have provided a solution for your original post as well as for the subsequent posts that you provided.

```
import json

data = '{"abc":null, \
         "data":[{"admin":0, "customer":"no", \
                  "info":{"id":76, "type":"guest"}}, \
                  {"admin":0, "customer":"no"}, \
                  {"info":{"id":73, "type":"member"}}]}'
                  # Added {} around "admin":0, "customer":"no"
                  # Added {} around "info":{"id":73, "type":"member"}
ans = json.loads(data)
result1 = ans['data'][0]['info']['type']
result2 = ans['data'][2]['info']['type']
print([result1, result2])
# OUTPUT == ['guest', 'member']

data2 = '{"abc":null, "data":\
         [{"admin":0, "customer":"no", \
           "info":{"id":76, "type":"guest"}}, \
          {"admin":0, "customer":"no", \
           "info":{"id":73, "type":"member"}}]}'

ans2 = json.loads(data2)
result1 = ans2['data'][0]['info']['type']
result2 = ans2['data'][1]['info']['type']
print([result1, result2])
# OUTPUT == ['guest', 'member']
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you check the edit and help me solve this new problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that according to your JSON data, the 'data' field inside your JSON is a collection. So it returns a Collection when calling it. So the field 'info' can be accessed by iterating over the collection.

```
for k in a["data"]:
  print(k["info"]["type"])
```

The above would print the value of the 'type' field.

You can also access the 'type' field by using a specific index:

```
a["data"][0]["info"]["type"]
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you check the edit and help me solve this new problem? Thank you.